# Detect changes in differently hosted asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have two different websites of my own company which are hosted in different servers with different databases. One(site1) is a type of site with actual content and another is the main site(site2) through which registered user can reach to the site1.

I need to detect changes or updates in the content site(site1) and reflect it in my main site(site2). The users while logged in to main site(site2) can visualize the changes in content site(site1) and if they need to go to the next site(site1) only they are redirected to that site(site1).

Is there any way to detect the changes and updates of the next site(site1) keeping different databases?

Both the sites are `asp.net` site and hosted in different servers in same `application pool (ASP.NET v4).`

Comment: they cant be on the same application pool if they are on different servers, im assuming you mean the same type of application pool?

Comment: are they the same code just deployed to two different servers

Comment: Yes, the same type of application pool. But with different codes.